# DbReader IndexOutOfRangeException perfomance hit

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception, indexoutofrangeexception

With the function `GetValueIfColumnExist`, I catch the situation that if the `DbReader` does not contain the column name. However, performing this with the `Map` function we measure a big hit on performance. Namely:

- Inmeasurable with `GetValue`
- Between 2.2s - 0.9s `GetValueIfColumnExist`

I want to do this so that I can have a single `Map` function for multiple call functions.

Does someone know why this specific catch case causes such a performance hit?

```
static public T GetValue<T>(this DbDataReader reader, string Parameter, T Default)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    var result = reader[Parameter] == DBNull.Value ? Default : (T)reader[Parameter];
    var time = DateTime.Now - dateTime;
    return result;
}

static public T GetValueIfColumnExist<T>(this DbDataReader reader, string Parameter, T Default)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    try
    {
        return reader.GetValue(Parameter, Default);
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now - dateTime;
        return Default;
    }
}

private Item Map(DbDataReader reader)
{
    return new Item()
    {
        Id = reader.GetValue("Id", -1),
        Name = reader.GetValue("Name", string.Empty),
        Description = reader.GetValue("Description", string.Empty),
        Position = new Position()
        {
            Index = reader.GetValueIfColumnExist("PositionId", 0),
            Name = reader.GetValueIfColumnExist(PositionName", string.Empty),
        }
    };
}
```

#### Update 1

Using the suggestions out of the comments the updated `GetValueIfColumnExist` does not hit significant perfomance issues.

However, further testing has shown that there is no performance increase between the debug and release version.

Further more this is inside legacy code so stepping over to an ORM is currently out of the question for now and was not not my orginal question. As to why there is such a noticable perfomance hit *here* when catching for exeption?

```
static public T GetValueIfColumnExist<T>(this DbDataReader reader, string Parameter, T Default)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) { 
                if (reader.GetName(i) == Parameter) {
                    return reader[i] == DBNull.Value ? Default : (T)reader[i];
                }
            }
            return Default;
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent Dapper. Why not use that instead? Writing your own boilerplate for processing data readers is tedious, not to mention unlikely to reach the same performance levels. The perf hit is likely coming only when you debug this code, as an attached debugger makes exception handling very slow. There's still a perf hit when not debugging, but less noticeable; in any case it's avoided by caching (and using) the results of `.FieldCount` and `.GetName`, which requires a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: Exceptions are expensive. Maybe you can create a list of all column names and check against that before calling reader[Parameter]?

Comment: 1. As for not using Dapper. That is what happens when your working with legacy code. Which makes it better to write database conntroller in the same way then introducing new frameworks. Especially if you dont have the time to do it.

2. Release version and Debug version does not show significant differance. (still above 0.9s)

3. Using the non Exception form using `.GetName` and `.FieldCount` has signficant perfomance increase. Form load time slaced to 1/8 the time which is acceptable.

Comment: `GetName` will only have a perf hit if you are calling it every time. Cache it once per resultset. Exceptions are really expensive: everything stops for tea every time you get an exception.

Comment: Note that I said nothing about release vs. debug, but whether you've got a debugger attached ("start" vs. "start without debugging"). The latter is what causes massive slowdowns, not (generally) the former. There is a common misconception that exception handling is very slow in .NET; this was true in 1.x, but generally hasn't been accurate for a long time. Notwithstanding that you should still avoid throwing them in tight loops, of course, since it is still much slower than a normal branch (which in turn is slower than not branching at all).

Comment: Then as addition that the release version was tested without attached debugger. I just find it strange that a literal second is needed for exception handeling for a list of 3 - 5 items are parsed. With other words the Erlang/Elixir notion of "Let it fail" is not applicable in .NET.